# burning DVD data to blank DVD

Tags: dvd

I have two DVDs to burn. I have MagicISO, and the data to burn is already in DVD format (you know, a VIDEO_TS folder full of `VIDEO_TS.BUP`, `VIDEO_TS.IFO`, `VIDEO_TS.VOB`, `VTS_01_0.BUP`, etc). If I just burn the `VIDEO_TS` folder onto a DVD with magicISO, will it work correctly?

Also, one of them is over 7GB, but the DVDs can only hold 4.7GB. How can I split them up?

Comment: related question: http://superuser.com/questions/109166/can-i-create-a-dvd-from-a-video-ts-folder/109223#109223

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must shrink the DVD files first before being able to burn them to a 4.7 GB DVD media. Or use a dual layer DVD.

[DVDShrink](http://www.dvdshrink.org/) is one tool to shrink DVDs. It's not new but it always worked good for me.

Comment: can I just burn the data straight onto the DVD and it will work correctly in a DVD player?

Comment: yes, it will, as long as you keep the files with the same names in the VIDEO_TS directory.

Comment: Depends how you burn it actually, and how new your DVD player is. If you burn it as a data DVD, only relatively newer DVD players will read it. If your burning program supports burning as a video DVD, it'll work on anything.

Comment: @emgee: that's not really accurate.  "video DVDs" are plain old data DVDs, usually using the UDF v1.02 filesystem.  the "video DVD" is a content standard -- a `VIDEO_TS` folder with the proper .IFO, .BUP and .VOB files inside it is all that's needed.